# Finding scalar propagators in QFT for specific spacetime dimension $d$ and mass $m$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, greens-functions, propagator

I need to understand how in practice one finds propagators for given $d$ and $m$ in quantum field theory. I can write down the theory provided for it but I don't know how to use it.

---

We will compute the standard Green’s functions and solutions (“propagators” or “2-point functions”). We use the coordinates $x = (t,\overrightarrow{x} )$. We start from the Euclidean Green's function $G^E (x)$, and then we apply

$
G^{F/\overline{F}}(t,\overrightarrow{x}) = \pm i G^E (\pm it, \overrightarrow{x}),
$

$
G^{\vee/\wedge}(t,\overrightarrow{x}) = \theta(\pm t - |\overrightarrow{x}|) \big (G^F (t,\overrightarrow{x}) + G^{\overline{F}}(t,\overrightarrow{x}) \big ),
$

$
G^{PJ}(t,\overrightarrow{x}) = G^\vee (t,\overrightarrow{x}) - G^{\wedge}(t,\overrightarrow{x}),
$

$
G^{(\pm)}(t,\overrightarrow{x}) = i G^\overline{F} (t,\overrightarrow{x}) - i G^{\vee/\wedge}(t,\overrightarrow{x} ).
$

Hint: Show that the Euclidean Green Function in $d=2$ is given by $G^E(x)=\frac{\ln |x|}{2 \pi}$ up to an overall constant.

---

The specific problem that I'd like to be able to solve is:

Find propagators for $d=1+2$ and $m=0$.

---

If any additional theory is needed please let me know. I can also provide

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to aid you in finding a solution to your problem. First, start with the recipe
$$G^E(it,\vec{x})=-iG^F(t,\vec{x})$$
and then consider the definition of $G^F(t,\vec{x})$, i.e.
$$G^F(t,\vec{x})=
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^d}\int d^dp\frac{e^{ip\cdot x}}{p^2+m^2-i\epsilon}$$
where $\epsilon$ is a very small quantity.

Then, set $m=0,\ d=2+1$, substitute $G^F(t,\vec{x})$ in $G^F(it,\vec{x})$ and do the calculations...

If something is not clear, please let me know.

Comment: Shouldn't we start from the Euclidean Green's function $G^E (x)$ as the problem states instead of going straight to the propagators' formulas? And I don't know what the form should be, i.e. in 4 dimensions it would be $G^E (x) = \frac{m}{4\pi^2 |x|} K_1 (m|x|)$ and I don't know how one finds that, this and the integral formulas are just scraps of information I was able to find, the problem itself doesn't provide them.

Comment: Hmmm... I recall such a derivation in a "QFT in curved spacetimes" book, I think Birell's and Davies' one. Perhaps try it out?